# Blocking facebook on Cisco RV042 Router Issue

Tags: router, cisco

I have this router and have configured some Access rules to block facebook. I was only able to block them when accessing facebook via "web browser" on both mobile and desktops. Both www.facebook.com and m.facebook.com were blocked. But this seems doens't take effect on the facebook mobile app. I was wondering if the app is using a different IP or what? What am I missing?

Comment: Try the domains listed here https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/417078-block-mobile-facebook-app-on-school-wireless-network?page=1#entry-2781825

Comment: I have tried all those and seems that I even have more ip blocks than those listed on that site. And someone also replied there that seems to have the same problem as mine. Anyway, thank you so much for your help man!

Comment: You could configure logging on your router, fire up the mobile app and see where the request is going.  If your router doesn't support that, then you could use some sort of debugging proxy like fiddler for your mobile os of choice.

Comment: Are you blacklisting DNS or specific IPs?

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks more like a "what IPs/methods does the Facebook app use?" than a security question. The suggestion above is the best: fire up the app and see where the traffic goes.

Comment: I've flagged this question due to the fact I don't deem it to be about Information Security. You're essentially asking (as mentioned by Schroeder) what method does the Facebook app use to direct traffic.